# when loading swiper slide, height changes

Tags: javascript, html, swiper.js

[image]

[image]

I'm initializing swiper with below code:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    speed: 400,
    slidesPerView: 3,
    autoplay: {
    delay: 3000,
    },
});
```

But when the page loads it shows big blue space followed by slides which adds to Layout shift in Google Pagespeed score. Can anybody point out whats wrong?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem and it looks complex. If you always know the final height of the carousel you can simply set a max-height on the swiper-container to minimize the problem but obviously it's not a solution.

As the carousel calculates it's dimensions by JS, if you need it to be "responsive" it's tricky to match the content before and after Swiper loads. Another way to deal with this is to avoid showing the Swiper element until it's fully loaded but you need to deal with the empty space so it does not affect elements under it.

Comment: @SergiRamón I agree, hiding it until its fully loaded also amounts to high Cummulative Layout Shift Scores, thus lowering our PageSpeed score. We need to know the algorithm/calculation it does for calculating height which is kind of hidden in the library code..

Answer (score 0):

E D I T:

Just select the swiper default wrapper and set it's height & width properties to whatever size you wish like this:

```
.swiper-wrapper {
  max-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vw;
}
```

By default this should do it, you might also want check if you didn't set specific dimensions on single slides in your css!